# Is it possible to order individual academic journals?

Tags: journals

Is it possible to order a physical copy of an academic journal? If I were published and wanted a copy of that Issue to keep, could I buy a physical copy? The journal that I might be published in is Journal of Vacuum Science and Technology A, which is an AIP journal.

Comment: Well, as long as the publisher actually prints paper copies, I don't see why you *wouldn't* be able to get a copy. But if it's *your* paper, why not just print off your PDF of it?

Comment: I received issues of JVSTB on paper in the past. Although I have to admit that these were special issues from conferences, where I attended.

Comment: Don't know about that journal, but many journals have web sites including information about subscriptions and single-issue prices.

Comment: Some journals used to send a "glossy" copy of a published article to the corresponding author.

Comment: If you are going to stay in academia, the coolness will wear off pretty quickly. I wouldn't spend the money to buy the journal issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some journals are on-line only and some are both on-line and print, and a few still print only. Since journals generally want to keep costs down and the printing process takes quite a lot including postage the trend is for all journals to drop print. Left is the possibility of print-on-demand but I am not sure this will be a possibility. I have yet to see any on-line journals offer such printing.

So while that was the general picture, in your case, you need to contact the journal. If they print copies, they should be able to sell you one. But, such a request should best be made when you provide your final manuscript of proofs, not long after the fact, the reason being that no-one sits on stocks of printed journals, they minimize the number of prints produced.

So: contact the editor and ask is the simple answer.

Comment: I was writing an answer almost exactly like this one... However, contact details of the journal editors in question and subscription details can be found [here](http://scitation.aip.org/content/avs/journal/jvsta/info/subscriptions).

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, it is possible. But as noted in the comments, it depends on the journal. Most of them have this information on their websites.